# How to update 100 iPad's?

Tags: ios, ipad, automation, mobile-device-management

Last year, I had to update 100 iPad to iOS 8. I did them one at a time and it took forever.

We use AirWatch as our MDM.

Is there a better way to update them all?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You'll want to look at caching server on OS X to avoid downloading 100 copies of the software image and either [ground control](https://www.groundctl.com) or [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12). Both can be highly automated and scripted and will re-enroll the devices into your MDM once the job is done.

Comment: The computers available to us are Windows ONLY. Cant use Apple Configurator or OS X Caching Server. Isn't there anything else thats FREE to help me? To get approval to buy Ground Control would take too long and my deadline to update them would have already passed

Comment: @softwareisfun sometimes when you can't plan ahead or get the tools that work, you just have to do it manually. Look into getting a used Mac for tuned to time, though. It's far superior to iTunes.